# Change the value of a variable with a button (Tkinter)

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want to change the value of a variable just with a button, i don't want to create a new entire function just like that:

```
from Tkinter import *
variable = 1
def makeSomething():
    global variable
    variable = 2
root = Tk()
myButton = Button(root, text='Press me',command=makeSomething).pack()
```

How i can do that?
(I need to do that for six buttons, making six functions it's not an option)

Comment: Why not? It's only three lines.

Comment: Only three lines, but if i need to make this for 6 buttons...

Comment: Then you should write in question that you have to make this for 6 buttons. It need different answer.

Comment: I think that the answer it's the same, i just want to take less work :/

Comment: For 2 buttons I would do `copy/paste` for more buttons I wouldn'd do `copy/paste` - so information `6 buttons` change the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> i need to make this for 6 buttons...

If each button modifies the same global variable, then have `make_something` accept a `value` parameter:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
variable = 1
def make_something(value):
    global variable
    variable = value
root = Tk()
Button(root, text='Set value to four',command=lambda *args: make_something(4)).pack()
Button(root, text='Set value to eight',command=lambda *args: make_something(8)).pack()
Button(root, text='Set value to fifteen',command=lambda *args: make_something(15)).pack()
#...etc
```

If each button modifies a different global, then condense all your globals into a single global dict, which `make_something` can then modify.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
settings = {"foo": 1, "bar": 1, "baz": 1}

def make_something(name):
    settings[name] = 2

root = Tk()
Button(root, text='Set foo',command=lambda *args: make_something("foo")).pack()
Button(root, text='Set bar',command=lambda *args: make_something("bar")).pack()
Button(root, text='Set baz',command=lambda *args: make_something("baz")).pack()
#...etc
```

In either case, you still only require one function.

---

If lambdas aren't to your taste, you could use nested functions to create separate callables for each command:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
settings = {"foo": 1, "bar": 1, "baz": 1}

def make_callback(key):
    def make_something(*args):
        settings[key] = 2
    return make_something

root = Tk()
Button(root, text='Set foo',command=make_callback("foo")).pack()
Button(root, text='Set bar',command=make_callback("bar")).pack()
Button(root, text='Set baz',command=make_callback("baz")).pack()
#...etc
```

---

... And you can avoid globals by instead using attributes of a class instance:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = {"foo": 1, "bar": 1, "baz": 1}
        self.root = Tk()
        Button(self.root, text='Set foo',command=self.make_callback("foo")).pack()
        Button(self.root, text='Set bar',command=self.make_callback("bar")).pack()
        Button(self.root, text='Set baz',command=self.make_callback("baz")).pack()
        #...etc

    def make_callback(self, key):
        def make_something(*args):
            self.settings[key] = 2
        return make_something

gui = GUI()
```

---

By the way, don't do this:

```
myButton = Button(root).pack()
```

This assigns the result of `pack()` to myButton, so myButton will be `None` instead of referring to your button. Instead, do:

```
myButton = Button(root)
myButton.pack()
```

Comment: This is the answer. I would comment that this forces two features that one should try to avoid:  `lambda functions` and `globals`. The user has to use one or the other.... can this be avioided with an `args` parameter in tkinter in 2022 or is this the best it can do ?

Comment: @D.L, to the best of my knowledge there's no `args` parameter for widget commands. Not even in 2022 ;-) However, it is still possible to avoid lambdas and globals. In general, lambdas can be replaced with ordinary functions 99.999% of the time. Globals can often be replaced by encapsulating your code in a class. I've updated my post with examples. IMO, a simple GUI can be functional/readable even with lambdas and globals, but I don't mind if someone goes the extra distance to avoid them.

Comment: it turn out that you can bypass globals with `tk.stringVar()` and `tk.intVar()` and so forth and using the `get()` and `set()`methods. So this is useful to know...

Answer (score 0):

Update : 
I have it working (almost) fine 
This code works but I'd like to display in real time
And when I uncoment the 2 things it doesn't do anything anymore

```py
def BotPlay_Button():
    nPlay = entryN.get()
    jlist = [Joueur(File1,True,File1),Joueur(File2,True,File1)]
    Partie = Partie_Object(jlist)
    for i in range(int(nPlay)):
        Play_Partie(Partie)
        xList.append(i)
        y1List.append(bot1.score)
        y2List.append(bot2.score)
        # windo.update_idletasks()
        # windo.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm a beginner but i think you should give the function 2 parameters one for the variable name and one for it value like this

```
def makeSomething(variableName,variableValue)
    variableName = variableValue
```

but as i said i'm a beginner so i could be wrong

Comment: Welcome to SO!Please make sure to ask questions in line with the [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should make you question more clear.

Comment: @JacoSolari This is an answer.

Comment: Hello R3GUL4R, what your function actually does is replace the value of `variableName` with the value of `variableValue`. Both of these, `variableName` and `variableValue` are actually variables themselves.

Comment: Hi, you forgot colon after function definition.